# How to combine Jetty with embedding ServletContextHandler and AbstractHandler?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jetty

Is it possible to realize Jetty server by java that will listening to different ports and has two different handlers (ServletContextHandler/extends AbstractHandler)?
I have json request/response service that work on port 8899 (extends AbstractHandler) and webapp that work on port 8080 (ServletContextHandler) at one Jetty server.

Here is ServletContextHandler, listening 8080:

```
private static ServletContextHandler getServletContextHandler() throws IOException {
    WebAppContext contextHandler = new WebAppContext();
    contextHandler.setErrorHandler(null);
    contextHandler.setContextPath(CONTEXT_PATH);

    WebApplicationContext context = getContext();

    contextHandler.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new DispatcherServlet(context)), CONTEXT_PATH);
    contextHandler.addEventListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));
    contextHandler.setResourceBase(new ClassPathResource("webapp").getURI().toString());
    contextHandler.setDescriptor("/webapp/WEB-INF/webstat.xml");
    return contextHandler;
}

private static WebApplicationContext getContext() {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    context.setConfigLocation("webapp/WEB-INF/");
    log.info("CONTEXT name {} locations {}", context.getDisplayName(), context.getConfigLocations());

    return context;
}
```

Handler that listening 8899:

```
private class Handler extends AbstractHandler {

    public void handle(String target,
                       Request baseRequest,
                       HttpServletRequest request,
                       HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        String contentEncoding = request.getHeader(RpcClient.CONTENT_ENCODING);
        String contentType = request.getHeader(RpcClient.CONTENT_TYPE);
        if ((contentEncoding != null && contentEncoding.startsWith(RpcClient.APPLICATION_JSON))||
                contentType.equals(RpcClient.APPLICATION_JSON)) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);

        } else {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE);
        }
        baseRequest.setHandled(true);
    }
}
```

And finally method that realize Jetty server:

```
 public void init() {
    try {
        Server httpServer = new Server();

        ServerConnector rpcConnector = new ServerConnector(httpServer);
        rpcConnector.setHost("localhost");
        rpcConnector.setPort(8899);
        rpcConnector.setIdleTimeout(30000);

        ServerConnector httpConnector = new ServerConnector(httpServer);
        httpConnector.setHost("localhost");
        httpConnector.setPort(8080);
        httpConnector.setIdleTimeout(30000);

        httpServer.setConnectors(new Connector[] {rpcConnector, httpConnector});

        HandlerList handlerList = new HandlerList();
        handlerList.setHandlers(new Handler[] {new Handler() }, new ContextHandler(getServletContextHandler()) {});//CAN'T APPLY them in HandlerList

        httpServer.setHandler(handlerList);
        httpServer.setStopAtShutdown(true);

        httpServer.start();
        log.info("WebServer start ...");
        httpServer.join();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error("Exception in http server. Exception: {}", ex.getMessage());
    }

}
```

I've check ContextHandlerCollection, HandlerList, HandlerCollection & etc.
The goal is to combine two different services for work at one jetty server. Logic of there work is that user go to `http://localhost:8080/getStatistics`, spring mvc send json request to `localhost:8899`, application collect statistics, and response it by json to spring mvc and it'll generate jsp with statistics to user.
Is any idea how to combine those Handlers?